# Google Cloud SQL access network

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform

In the Google Cloud console: MySQL-> myInstance-> Connectivity-> Authorized networks
I need to add an IP for my PC. SAVE gives me a message:

**Operation failed: Invalid request: disk size can only be set for Second Generation instances..**

How can I avoid this error? I didn't change the disk dimension.
I need to do the data export necessary to upgrade MySQL.

Comment: You can create a ticket for your error.

Comment: As @UGold has pointed out the best path would be opening a ticket with GCP Support team. However, before doing so you should try upgrading your SQL instance. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-2nd-gen) you'll find more information on how to upgrade First Generation instances to Second Generation instances.

Comment: Will migrating the database to the new MySQL version fix the problem?

Comment: It's not the version of MySQL that's the issue, it's the version of Cloud SQL instance. See here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/deprecation-notice for more information about the deprecation of first generation instances. It's still "supported" (ish) until March 2020, but more and more of these kinds of problems are likely to crop up. As previous folks said, you should be able to create a ticket to help with the authorized issue to get you past that, but it's just going to be a bandaid. Miguel is right, you will need to transition to a second generation Cloud SQL instance.

Comment: @GabeWeiss could you add your comment as an answer? for major visibility of the solution to the community.

Comment: Oh, yup! I had meant to and forgot. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm 99% sure it's not the version of MySQL that's the issue, it's the version of Cloud SQL instance. See here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/deprecation-notice for more information about the deprecation of first generation instances. It's still "supported" (ish) until March 2020, but more and more of these kinds of problems are likely to crop up.

As previous folks in the comments said, you should be able to create a ticket to help with the authorized issue to get you past that, but it's just going to be a bandaid. Miguel is right, you will need to transition to a second generation Cloud SQL instance.

Edit: For completeness, Here's the link on how to upgrade your instance that Miguel posted:

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/upgrade-2nd-gen

Answer (score 0):

The first generation is closed and "Connections" cannot be configured. The MySQL generation upgrade has solved the problem.